# Parsing JSON from jquery call with Django

Tags: django

I have a javascript object that looks like this:

```
var myObject = { "Danny": {"height": 1.70, "weight" : 70 }, "David" : {"height": 1.90, "weight" : 80" } ... }
```

I want to send it as a JSON to a django view and parse it in it.
On the client side, using jQuery, I added this:

```
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/ajax/someview",
          data: JSON.stringify(myObject),
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          dataType: "json"
      });
```

However, when I debug the view and look at request.POST, the data looks like this:

```
POST:<QueryDict: {u'{"Danny": {"height": 1.70, "weight" : 70 }, "David" : {"height": 1.90, "weight" : 80" }}' : [u'']}>
```

How can I convert this to a python object which i can work it (using simplejson.load)?

Thanks,
Joel

Answer (score 4):

You can access the raw POST data with - not surprisingly - `request.raw_post_data`. That will give you a string you can convert with `simplejson.loads()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/ajax/someview",
      data: {'mydata': JSON.stringify(myObject)},
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      dataType: "json"
});
```

Then get it with `request.POST.get('mydata')`